# react native modal not close after setState false

Tags: react-native

I have set modal visibility to false but it still showing. I cant figure out what causes this issue. this my code at loading.js.
I'm use this component in main what happen when setState false but its just close after close simolator and restart the device

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {View, Image, Modal, StyleSheet, Text} from "react-native";

export default class Loader extends Component{
    render(){
        const {animationType,modalVisible}=this.props;
        return(
            <Modal

                animationType={animationType}
                transparent={true}
                visible={modalVisible}>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
                        <Image
                            source={require('../img/loading.gif')}
                            style={styles.loaderImage}/>

                    </View>

                </View>

            </Modal>

        )
    }
}

Loader.propTypes={
    animationType:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    modalVisible:PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
```

this main class

```js
 export default class ForoshRah extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
            this.state = {
                image: null,
                images: null,
                loadingVisible:false,
            };
            this.onValueChange2=this.onValueChange2.bind(this);
            this.OnSubmiteData=this.OnSubmiteData.bind(this);
        }
        onValueChange2(value: string) {
            this.setState({
                Field: value,
            });
        }
        async OnSubmiteData(){
            this.setState({loadingVisible:true})
            let token = await    AsyncStorage.getItem('token',token);
            let response = await          
            fetch(url,{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    Authorization:'JWT'+" "+token,
                }

                ,body: JSON.stringify({
                    title,
     
                })
            })
            let register = await response.json();
            this.setState({userID:register.id})
            if(response.status===200){
                this.UploadImage()
            }
        }
        async UploadImage() {
    
            let token = await            AsyncStorage.getItem('token',token);
            let response = await fetch(url,{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    Authorization:'JWT'+" "+token,
                },body: formData
            })
            let uimage = await response;
            console.log('user',this.state.userID);
            if(response.status=200){

                handleCloseModal = () => {
                    console.log(this.state.loadingVisible);
                    this.setState({ loadingVisible: false})
                    });
                };
    this.props.navigation.dispatch({ type: 'Navigation/BACK' })

            }else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({ loadingVisible: false })
                }, 100)

            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({ loadingVisible: false })
            }, 100)
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <KeyboardAwareScrollView >

                    <View style={{marginBottom:'10%'}}>
                    <Button block  style={{backgroundColor:'#8e25a0'}}  onPress={this.OnSubmiteData.bind(this)}>
                    </Button>
                    </View>
                <Loader 
                        modalVisible={loadingVisible}
                        animationType="fade"
                />
                </KeyboardAwareScrollView>


                    );
        }
    }
```

onsubmitdata setState true and after response going to 200 Setstate set false in code main

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just call state name as you have did. You should do like below.

```
<Loader 
        modalVisible={this.state.loadingVisible}
         animationType="fade"
 />
```

Comment: Did you close and open the app? It’s strange if that doesn’t work. Just try to setState in onPress event of Button and check whether that will close the modal. Remember if modal didn’t close programmically by a button press or something, before try your code again, just close the app and open it. Otherwise modal will be stuck in your app.

Comment: im reload app but its still showing, ok I'm test this way

Comment: Don’t reload. Just close the app entirely and open again.